# How can I show that the function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have a function from an interval $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x/n$, where $n$ is a natural number.

How can I show that this function is measurable?

Comment: What are the properties about $f(x)$ that you know? Is it measurable on $I$? (Is there a printing mistake, should it be $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{n}$ ?)

Comment: yes it is equal to it, I just fixed the typo.

Comment: yes, it is equal.  I just fixed the typo.